# iPhone - Call a php page asynchronously and be sure it has been loaded

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

In one of my apps, I'd like to call asynchronously a php page I have written (http://serveradress/page.php?date=20111231), and I would be sure to know if the page could be called (no 404 error, php server down, customised 404 page, missing internet connection, or some things like that).
I've planned for that to make the php page return a very simple HTML page with just "OK" in its body or title.

This would be a "phantom" call without use of any UIWebView, or if REALLY nedded, a hidden UIWebView but I'd prefer to avoid this.

Could you help me to write this call ?
And be sure to know if it has been loaded ?

I saw that I should probably use NSURLConnection, but I'm a little bit lost.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSURLConection is very good solution for asynchronous loading. There are few steps for creating one.

**1. Setup your NSURLConnection**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // your code...
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]];
}
```

*`responseData` is your NSMutableData iVar.*

**2. Implement delegate methods**

a) In this method we will check for HTTP status codes

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)]) {
        int statusCode = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
        if (statusCode >= 400) {
            [connection cancel]; 
            NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Server returned status code %d",@""),statusCode] forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            NSError *statusError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSHTTPPropertyStatusCodeKey code:statusCode userInfo:errorInfo];
           [self connection:connection didFailWithError:statusError];
        }
    }
}
```

b) This creates your NSData component

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

c) Handles successful url connection

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // do whatever you want using responseData as your server output
}
```

d) Handles errors

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // handle your error
}
```

*You can get error info using `[error userInfo]` And display it in UIAlertView, for example.*

---

So as I said NSURLConnection is very good solution, **but** you should also look at [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). :)

Comment: @Kashiv : Thank you, I'm trying this. I wonder, how may I know the kind of value returned in the NSData ? It can be anything else than a string...

Comment: @Kashiv : NSHTTPPropertyStatusCodeKey si said deprecated. What should I use instead. I'm searching for a replacement but I don't find the right one. STrange thing, even if said deprecated, NSHTTPPropertyStatusCodeKey is not recognized ar compile time. It's the only error.

Comment: Sorry for that. As the _errorDomain_ you can use any string, for example @"HTTPStatusCode". Please check if this works ;)

Comment: @Kashiv : Yes :-)  That's what I've done :-)  But for the NSData, I can receive the string I send myself, but I can also receive any other things if the request does not succeed as I expect. How may I know what kind of data I've received ?

Comment: What kind of data your server can return?

Comment: @Kashiv : I don't know. It's not MY server. It's my Webpage and the server can return whatever it wants if it doens't want my webpage to be available.

Comment: But waht type of data? I mean image, text, html, error page, etc.? You can use **id obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:responseData];** and after that **if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])** or **[UIImage class]**. Then, via if statement you can handle it in multiple ways. But if your server will return a **bad status code**, connection:didFailWithError: will be called instead.