# iPhone can't download Image (BLOB) from MySQL

Tags: iphone, mysql, image, parsing, blob

I have a MySQL database that contains images which I'd like to download into my iPhone App. The images are stored as BLOBs. I have a PHP script that can grab any of these images from the DB and display them on a web-page. For this I use:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageName = '$nameOfImage'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$image = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header('Content-type: ' . $image['mime_type']);
header('Content-length: ' . $image['file_size']);

echo $image['file_data'];
```

This works perfectly well, so far so good.

But how do I get these images into my *app*? 
I've successfully parsed XML before in my apps - but I was parsing text-data. How do you do this with BLOBS?  What PHP code do I need to generate XML that I can then parse to get BLOB data? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you download your image using `NSURLConnection`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    UIImage *downloadedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    // deal with it!
}
```

If not, you have to find a property that holds the response data (and it's probably called `responseData`), so init your image with it.

Comment: but I'm _not_ downloading my image with `NSURLConnection` :-) I'm trying to parse XML, as I described in my question. If however I were to try and use `NSURLConnection` - which I know nothing about - well, _can_ I even use it to access info from a MySQL database? Is that even possible? If so, how?

Comment: The code you posted shows a php file which outputs an image. So, all you have to do is download it. Here's a tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918473/iphone-call-a-php-page-asynchronously-and-be-sure-it-has-been-loaded/5919656#5919656